# How to initialize and destroy Non-contextual CDI bean initialization PROPERLY

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi, java-ee-7

I have a Controller instance. This is NON contextual CDI bean. I want to inject CDI beans into my controller instance. I coded like this:

```
MyController controller = myWayToCreateController();

CreationalContext<Controller> ctx = beanManager.createCreationalContext(null);
AnnotatedType<Controller> at = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(MyController.class);
InjectionTarget<Controller> it = beanManager.createInjectionTarget(at);

it.inject( controller, ctx);      // LINE 1
it.postConstruct( controller);    // LINE 2
// ctx.release();                 // LINE 3

// .................
// ......Use controller here
// .................

// Later, I destroy my controller

it.preDestroy(controller);        // LINE 4
it.dispose(controller);           // LINE 5
ctx.release();                    // LINE 6
```

My question is:

```
Question1: Do I really need LINE 2, LINE 4 since my controller has no @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy.

Question1: Can I use LINE 3 instead of using LINE 6? I just want to release CreationalContext right after my controller initialized.
```